# How to unpack tree-like structures (like js objects or json) in function arguments?

Tags: python

I.g. we have fuction, which has argument called option, to which I'd like to pass some tree-like structure, which will describe what function need to do:

```
def do_some(option):
  pass

do_some({
  "column1": {
    "enable": True,
    "font": {
       "name": "Times",
       "size": 14,
    }
  },
  "column2": {...}
})
```

For sure we can iterate over collection inside function like this:

```
def do_some(option):
    for column in option:
        enable = option[column ].get("enable", False)
        print(column, enable)
```

but this nor elegant nor self-describing, or pass collection as **kwargs, but it will unpack only first level of tree.

What is pythonic way to deal with such structures?

Am I correct, that [TypedDict in PEP 0589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) are invented for such cases? Is there some solution for Python2?

Comment: How exactly do you want it to be unpacked? What if you have duplicate keys? Do you flatten the dictionary?

Comment: You specs are not very clear, it's hard to know what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: 1) Describe exactly what function is expect as input 2) parse the option somehow "pythonic", it's what I am asking for, what is "pythonic" way to deal with such args.

Comment: What is "I.g."?

Comment: Anton, what is wrong with simply using a dictionary and list comprehension? Could you edit your question and show what an "ideal" way would be? Pretend you have no constraints -- in a perfect world, how would you want to deal with the 'option' argument? We want to help, it is simply that we are not completely certain what results you desire.

Comment: Something like: for column in options: print column.font.size, and some type definition for what this function is expected in terms of dict keys for each tree level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little mind reading still involved in this question, but I think the munch library [munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch). Is probably what you are looking for. See below;

```
import munch

test = dict(
    column1=dict(
        enabled=True,
        font=dict( name = "Times", size=14),
    ),
    column2=dict(
        enabled=False,
        font=dict(name="Roman", size=12),
    )
)

munched = munch.munchify(test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    [print(v.enabled) for v in munched.values()]
    [print(v.font.name) for v in munched.values()]
```

**Gives;**

> True
>   False
>   Times
>   Roman

[Edit]

You could also be very explicit and get similar results using classes (granted, I don't know if all of the type annotation is available in 2.7)

```
from typing import List


class Font:
    def __init__(self, name: str, size: int):
        self.name = name    # type: str
        self.size = size    # type: int


class Colunm:
    def __init__(self, name: str, enabled: bool, font: Font):
        self.name = name
        self.enabled = enabled
        self.font = font


def foo(options: List[Colunm]):
    for o in options:
        print(o.font.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = [
        Colunm(name="Col1", enabled=True, font=Font("Times", 14)),
        Colunm(name="Col2", enabled=False, font=Font("Roman", 12))
    ]
    foo(options)
```

Comment: Yes, It's pretty much like this, suppose with type annotation using TypedDict is ok. Thanks.

Comment: I made an edit to show using classes as well, which gives you both the dot notation as well as explicit definitions.